# QGraphicsScene::~QGraphicsScene() segmentation fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qgraphicsscene

Good day!

With Qt 4.7.3 an example below crashes at QGraphicsScene::~QGraphicsScene() call:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // replace this with QObject app; and no problems
    QCoreApplication app( argc, argv );

    new QGraphicsScene( &app );

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

[Bug report](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-1060) created.

Comment: Is this your actual code? What is `new QGraphicsScene( &app );` supposed to do?

Comment: yes, it's actual code after many simplifications. This line creates unnamed object in heap. I don't have any other files and use qmake for application building.

Comment: Yes, and when 'app' leaves scope it deletes child objects - QGraphicsScene instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `QGraphicsScene` instance is constructed it appends itself in a list stored in a private member of the single `QApplication` instance, and when it is deleted, it also remove itself from that list:

```
QGraphicsScene::~QGraphicsScene()
{
    Q_D(QGraphicsScene);

    // Remove this scene from qApp's global scene list.
    qApp->d_func()->scene_list.removeAll(this);

    ...
}
```

When the application object is destroyed, the inherited base class' destructors are called recursively, so, `~QApplication()` calls `~QCoreApplication()` which itself calls `~QObject()`.

The actual deletion of child objects is done in `~QObject()`. 
Which means that at the time the scene object is destroyed, all the `QApplication` members are already destroyed, so `~QGraphicsScene()` crashes when it tries to access the list.